# htaccess get запросы

Tags: php

После того как пользователь заходит на сайт, cloudflare перенаправляет пользователя на страницу с таким get содержимым:
https://site.com/?__cf_chl_managed_tk__=pmd_8056EuEOMgX255fUWFJF_z1qXkFWyx6E6HTDchjhT.s-1633006005-0-gqNtZGzNAqWjcnBszRPR

https://site.com/categories/shoes?__cf_chl_managed_tk__=pmd_8056EuEOMgX255fUWFJF_z1qXkFWyx6E6HTDchjhT.s-1633006005-0-gqNtZGzNAqWjcnBszRPR

Как сделать 301 редирект с сохранением url (категории, другие страницы сайта) и удалением GET запроса?

Чтобы в url удалялось все после ?_

Comment: а у вас гет-параметры нигде прям вот вообще не используются?

Comment: Не используются

Comment: либо как удалить конкретно этот запрос?

Answer (score 0):

отфильтруйте по параметру и перешлите в текущий путь обрезав сами параметры с помощью `?` в конце перенаправления.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} __cf_chl_managed_tk__
RewriteRule (.*)    $1?    [R=301,L]
```